# Images not showing in browser on Android

Tags: android, css, image

I am currently developing a website, which - of course - also needs to be responsive. Everything is working correctly on iOS as well as Android, except the fact that he isn't showing three particular images in a slideshow on Android *(tested on the Samsung S5, S3, Galaxy Tab 3 / Lollipop, Jelly Bean / Default browser, Chrome)*. He does show the rest of the images.

I am adding these images through JS as background-image of the right div:

```
        $('.header__slideshow--frame').each(function (index) {
            $(this).css({
                'width': slider.parts.header.width(),
                'background-image': 'url(' + (dir + slider.images.links[index]) + ')'
            });
        });
```

Where the styling for the frame is:

```
    .header__slideshow {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        left: 0;
        height: 102%;
        z-index: -1000;
        margin-top: -15em;
        background: $greyOne url('../images/slider-placeholder.png') no-repeat center 35%;

        .header__slideshow--frame {
            float: left;
            height: 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: bottom center;
            background-size: cover;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
        }
    }
```

All images are .jpg format, not bigger than 260KB, have a maximum width of 1600px and if I open them directly through the browser he is showing them.

I have already tried to change the (max-)height, (max-)width, position, z-index, full path to the images, adding them as .png, removing the background 'cover' property et cetera.

Does anyone have any idea, suggestion or tip for debugging these kind of problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check the path to the images if it is correct, one way is to try to load the page on computer browser instead of a phone.  Look at the LogCat debug info and see if any exceptions are being thrown, such as outofmemory exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I am sure the paths are correct and I will definitely try to debug with the LogCat info. But still weird he is loading them on all iOS devices, but not on Android devices - right? Could it also be something with the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer! I was adding different images for tablet and phones, like this

```
        var dir = this.images.base;
        if (isTablet) dir += 'tablet/';
        if (isPhone) dir += 'phone/';
```

But JavaScript recognized the website both as Android phone as tablet, so he was adding a path like "images/tablet/phone/..."